# Can cronjob execute multiple functions within a same php file different?

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron

I have order, shipping and product functions within the same class. each has a different cronjob settings. For example, product runs every 5 mins, shipping runs every 30 mins and order runs every hour. However, by checking the log, I notice that sometimes cron doesn't run exactly what I set it to. shipping function would run every 2,3 hours and order function would run every hour then every few hours. So I guess the question is, should I be splitting these cronjob functions to different php file? Could that be the reason that's causing cronjob not running correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt being in the same file would be the problem since cronjobs basically spawn a new thread per task.

I'd recommend you to log your functions call for more in-depth view.

```
<?php

file_put_contents('/tmp/cron_log', date('Y-m-d H:i:s).' > [your_function_name]', FILE_APPEND);
```

Putting this line in every fucntion (at beginning) will tell you whenever one object is instantiated (use : `tail -f /tmp/cron_log` in a terminal).